# How to remove inherited values from Sphinx source configuration?

Tags: sphinx

I have two sources configured in Sphinx. They look something like this:

```
source source_merchant_deal_en
{
    ...
    sql_query_post_index = UPDATE sphinx SET max_doc_id = max_doc_id_temp WHERE alias = "merchant_deal_en"
}

source source_delta_merchant_deal_en : source_merchant_deal_en
{
    ...
    sql_query_post_index =
}
```

The idea is that the delta index (specified as source_delta_merchant_deal_en) inherits pretty much everything from the main index (specified as source_merchant_deal_en), but should NOT inherit sql_query_post_index. The only info I could find on explicitly clearing inherited configuration values is from [this Sphinx blog post from 2013](http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2013/11/05/sphinx-configuration-features-and-tricks/), which I'm following in the above example. However, it doesn't seem to actually work; the sql_query_post_index query is being run by both the main index job as well as the delta index job.

Is there a newer way of preventing sql_query_post_index from being inherited from the parent source configuration? Or will I have to rewrite the configuration so that the delta is completely separate from the main and doesn't inherit at all?

Comment: What's the Sphinx version? Leaving it empty in the inherited config works just fine for me.

Comment: We're running 2.2.9-id64-release (rel22-r5006).

Comment: It turns out I misread the Sphinx config. It was cancelling out `sql_query_post`, not `sql_query_post_index`. Thanks for your patience, StackOverflow community!